# Using Ajax to send form data

Tags: php, ajax, webforms

I have a HTML/PHP form using using post to send form data to a script php file. I want to send the data with out the page reloading upon clicking the submit button.

I am wondering how do implement AJAX to allow this functionality.

I have a good grasp of Javascript but have never used ajax technology.

If this question is beyond the scope of this Q&A if anyone could please point me in the right direction to a good tutorial That will allow me to implement this technology with out having to spend a couple of days learning how it all works. I am working with a very short deadline.

Cheers.

Comment: I'll recomend you start here which will simply explain how to accomplish your needed task: http://www.captain.at/howto-ajax-form-post-get.php Learn the basics of javascript and Ajax before jumping into Jquery that way you'll be able to pin point Jquery problems as well.

Comment: @Codex73 cheers for that. Gave me a good understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `serialize` and then `post` form data with jquery and optionally handle the response.

the following is an example from jquery's documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your first AJAX experience, I recommend a good toolkit like jQuery.

See:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks dkamins I've touched on jQuery before. I'll check that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this jQuery plugin:
http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html

It also has form validation and works on IE6.

Answer (score -1):

basically, you can do no wrong by using jquery javascript library with all the cool nifty functions ready, including ajax function which allows you to do ajax call with something as simple as [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

but if you're looking for a [step by step tutorial, then you might want to look at this](http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/).